# NavigationBar hides TableView in TabBarViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a ViewController that Pushes a TabBarViewController. Inside that TabBar View Controller I have 4 tabs. Two of these tab bars are UITableViewControllers and the other two are ViewControllers. The first tab is a table view controller and is working fine, ie not being hidden by the navigation bar. The third tab, which is another TableViewController, is being partially covered by the navigation bar. The first section and first cell is being hidden underneath the navigation bar. Has anyone had this problem in the past or does anyone know a solution to this? I've tried a couple of things like resizing the frame size manually

`self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,self.view.bounds.size.width -20, self.view.bounds.size.height-20);`

That did't seem to work. I tried AutoLayout as well and didn't work. I don't know what else to do. Anyone have any suggestions or ideas of how to tackle this.

Edit: I've tried the `edgesForExtendedLayout` but it is making my navigationbar a darker color. It animates the color change in the navigationbar, sort of like a loading bar.

Note: This is only happening in ios7. I just simulated it in iOS 6.1 and the navigationbar does not cover the table view controller at all, which is weird to me. Any one have any suggestions?

Edit #2: Noticing that this is an iOS 7 > problem i did the following but now the navigation bar has changed color to a darker color.

```
if([[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0] intValue] >= 7)
    {
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        {
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
            self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the viewDidLoad method of UITableViewController (assuming it's loaded with a call to the tabBarController) that is associated with the tabs use

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0., 0., CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0);
}
```

Comment: Using your code in the viewDidLoad of my UITableViewController, it didn't work and also made the tabBar a translucent black-ish/grey-ish color.

Comment: I had to set it in the viewDidLoad of the TabBarViewController. That fixed the layout/edges problem but now my navigation bar turns darker.

Comment: Make `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;`

Comment: It still turns the nav bar dark, in an animated fashion I may add.
Link to it loading: http://i.imgur.com/mriSAly.png

Link to it full: http://i.imgur.com/lKmc3Vh.png

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that with:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    viewcontroller.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    viewcontroller.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
    viewcontroller.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Comment: where did you put this? The AppDelegate? Or inside the TabBarViewController's View Did Load?

Comment: I set it into ViewDidLoad

Comment: I put this inside my TabBarViewController's view did load and it's working, sort of. Now the navigationbar turned into a dark color and the simulator blinks a bit before it pushes all the way to the new view controller. Any fixes for that?